# Auto add image to node listing from node body field | DRUPAL

Tags: image, drupal, summary

Hi I have news content type, where are fields Title(textbox), Body(text with CKeditor) and Summary Image(multimedia asset). Is it possible to automatically add first image from Body to summary image field on form save?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not or at least not so easy. You will need a custom parser here and a preproccess function.

Why not using an **extra img field** that will display only on the teaser display (I say Teaser instead of Summary since it is used more in Drupal like this) or just **use the first image** of the Summary Image (multimedia asset) field using [image_delta_formatter](https://drupal.org/project/image_delta_formatter) module?